# Refresh page every couple minutes

Tags: javascript

I need to open `192.168.1.1` every couple of minutes. I have the following code but doesn't work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    setInterval(function() {
      location.replace("http://192.168.1.1")
    }, 60 * 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you control the code of `http://192.168.1.1`?

Comment: What do you mean control the code? Its the router IP address that needs to be refreshed..

Comment: Check my answer then, it should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the iframe solution, in case you want it to open in a new tab

```
<script>

var URL = "http://example.com";
setInterval(function() {
    var win = window.open(URL, "_blank");
    /* uncomment if you want it to close
    setInterval(function() {
        win.close() 
            }, 1500);   
    */
}, 2000);

</script>
```

like the iframe, not replacing the current tab ensures your code keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work as you want it to, because once you change the location for the first time, it will load the router site and your code won't be executed anymore.

Since you can't control the router page code, you can load the router website into an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.1"></iframe>
```

and put this in your `<head>` to refresh the site every 300 seconds:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="300">
```

(adjust the number of seconds to your needs)